# Was the creation of Earth story has roots in the Rig Veda or somewhere else?

Tags: vishnu, rig-veda, indra, earth, brahmanas

Harivamsha in the mahAbharata - bhaviShyaparva  Chapter 34 describes as to how **viShNu** takes varAha avatAra to lift the Earth from Netherworld

---

There is a legend of creation in the [Taittiriya Brahmana](https://www.ibiblio.org/britishraj/Jackson1/chapter15.html).

> In the beginning there was nothing except water and a lotus leaf
> standing out of it. Prajapati dived in the shape of a boar and brought
> up some earth and spread it out and fastened it down by pebbles. This
> was the earth.

Similar story appears in [Satapatha brahmana.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe41/sbe4128.htm)

> He desired, 'May it become more than one, may it reproduce itself!' He
> toiled and practised austerity; and worn out with toil and austerity,
> he created foam. He was aware that 'this indeed looks different, it is
> becoming more (than one): I must toil, indeed!' Worn out with toil and
> austerity, he created clay, mud, saline soil and sand, gravel
> (pebble), rock, ore, gold, plants and trees: therewith he clothed this
> earth.

---

Peculiarly, a mantra is available in [Rig Veda II.20.7](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02020.htm)

> sa vṛtrahendraḥ kṛṣṇayonīḥ purandaro dāsīrairayad vi | ajanayan manave
> kṣāmapaśca satrā śaṃsaṃ yajamānasya tūtot ||
>
> Smasher of Vr̥tra, splitter of fortresses, Indra razed the Dāsa
> (fortresses) with their dark wombs. ***He gave birth to the earth and the
> waters for Manu***. In every way he makes the sacrificer’s laud powerful.

---

My question is - Was the creation of Earth story has roots in the Rig Veda or somewhere else?